# Frequent Disconnection from wirless router (Huawei LTE CPE E5173S-920)

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

My laptop is HP 650. I have wireless connection issues with my Huawei LTE CPE E51732-920 router as it keep disconnecting after few seconds of connection. Ethernet works fine though. I use the latest Ubuntu 13.10 with the latest updates.

I am a brand new Ubuntu user with very limited knowledge of programming. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

...could be a variety of issues:

1. check, it there is anyone else (WLAN-Router) on the same WLAN-Channel in your neighbourhood. It may block or interfere your own router's signal. Switch it to a channel less or not used by anyone. (another possibility: If your router AND computer supports switch to 5-GHz-Band)-------
   [edit] I just forgot: Some DECT-Phones for home use do interfere with a WLAN-Antenna - place it (if you do have one) somewhere else, at least 30cm/1foot away from the router
2. check, if there is the correct encryption switched in your routers' WLAN-Key (switching it from AES to TKIP, waiting a Minute and switching it back helped some time)
3. If these  do not help check, if there is an update available for your computers' WLAN-Unit. (I had a tablet which frequently lost connection and an update wiped it away)
4. Same as 3. but with the router: check for firmware-update.

If this all does not help, perhaps the router is gone: Try with another Unit (Smartphone etc.) if there you are encountering the same issues.

Comment: Thanks Christian, but I think its more complicated than that. First thing I noticed after switching to Ubuntu 13.10 was that my bluetooth driver wasnt responding again. There's still no bluetooth driver. Now its wireless 4G LTE connection, and its not working to. It was working very fine on 4G WIMAX, but not on LTE.